# Error while creating cognito-user-pool using aws cli - `Role does not have permission to publish with SNS`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I'm trying following command to create a cognito-user-pool using aws-cli.

```
await aws.command(
      `cognito-idp create-user-pool \
      --pool-name ${stackName} \
      --auto-verified-attributes email phone_number \
      --alias-attributes email phone_number preferred_username \
      --sms-verification-message 'Your authentication code for ${stackName} is {####}.' \
      --email-verification-message 'Your authentication code for ${stackName} is {####}.' \
      --email-verification-subject 'Your Verification Code for ${stackName}.' \
      --sms-authentication-message 'Your authentication code for ${stackName} is {####}.' \
      --mfa-configuration OPTIONAL \
      --email-configuration EmailSendingAccount='DEVELOPER',SourceArn='arn:aws:ses:${region}:${awsAccountId}:identity/${senderEmail}',From='${senderEmail}',ReplyToEmailAddress='${replyTo}' \
      --sms-configuration SnsCallerArn=arn:aws:iam::${awsAccountId}:role/service-role/${roleName},ExternalId=${externalId} \
      --account-recovery-setting RecoveryMechanisms=[{Priority=1,Name=verified_email},{Priority=2,Name=verified_phone_number}] \
      --device-configuration ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice=true,DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt=true \
      --verification-message-template '{"DefaultEmailOption":"CONFIRM_WITH_LINK","EmailSubjectByLink":"Your verification link","EmailMessageByLink":"Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}","SmsMessage":"Your authentication code for ${stackName} is {####}."}' \
      --admin-create-user-config '{"AllowAdminCreateUserOnly":false,"InviteMessageTemplate":{"EmailMessage":"Your username for ${stackName} is {username} and temporary password is {####}.","EmailSubject":"Your temporary password for ${stackName}","SMSMessage":"Your username for ${stackName} is {username} and temporary password is {####}."},"UnusedAccountValidityDays":7}' \
      `
    ).then(function (data) {
      console.log('in creating user-pool data=', data)
      return data.object.UserPool.Id
    })
```

It gave me following error.

```
An error occurred (InvalidSmsRoleAccessPolicyException) when calling the CreateUserPool operation: Role does not have permission to publish with SNS
' stdout = '' stderr = '
```

But weird thing is that if run the command with the failed parameters again, then it doesn't give the error and is run successfully.

Any suggestions are much appreciated for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your're using CloudFormation for deployment, but in my case, I had the same error because the creation of role + policy with "sns:Publish" permissions was overlapping with the creation of UserPool, so when the pool starts creation I had "Role does not have permission to publish with SNS" becase policy wasn't finished it's creation.

"DependsOn" didn't help, so I had to create role + policy on a different nested stack, so it can be created before the UserPool.

In your case, I think the first execution creates the role + policy, and fails on the pool creation, but in the second execution, as it has the role + policy already created, it succeeds.

This is an example of my case if it helps someone:

[image]

And the nested stacks to solve my issue:

```
CognitoIAM:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: 'cognito/cognito-iam-stack.yml'
    Parameters:
      Stage: !Ref Stage
      CognitoExternalId: !Ref CognitoExternalId

UserPoolStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: 'cognito/cognito-stack.yml'
    Parameters:
      Stage: !Ref Stage
      CognitoExternalId: !Ref CognitoExternalId
      CognitoSMSRoleArn: !GetAtt CognitoIAM.Outputs.CognitoSMSRoleArn
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue! I had to deploy the role & policy first, followed up by the userpool second! Thank you!